# Is it possible to add a node to a circuit model in SystemModeler?

Tags: system-modeler

I am putting together a basic electrical circuit model in Wolfram System Modeler.  While the circuit does not technically need a common node, it makes the circuit easier to explain as branches may be grouped logically.

I am currently trying a 0 ohm resistor as a common node.  If there is a way to insert a node on a wire that multiple elements may connect to, I will use that.

Answer (score 7):

*I am a developer working on SystemModeler*

There is unfortunately no way to create "nodes" in SystemModeler. This is mostly because the concept of a "node" does not exist in the underlying modeling language used by SystemModeler, Modelica.

This has been requested before, and is on our list of features to have in a future version.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are asking for, if it's just an electrical circuit you can add a `Pin`, see `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin`.

[image: small electrical circuit with a Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin]

If there are signals of different types (`Real`, `Boolean`, `Integer`, etc) you can use an `expandable connector`. I'd recommend taking a look at the example `BusUsage` ([Modelica.Blocks.Examples.BusUsage](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/Modelica/Modelica.Blocks.Examples.BusUsage.html))
[image: Bus connector]